# Adding relaxedQueryChars to tomcat 7.0.82 HTTP connector generates no matching property warning

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

We have the following in our `server.xml`:

```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="120000" 
               redirectPort="443" 
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" 
               relaxedQueryChars="{}" 
               ... />
```

We put in `relaxedQueryChars` to avoid warnings when we get HTTP requests with the curly brackets in the querystring. However, upon server startup we get

```
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'relaxedQueryChars' to '{}' did not find a matching property.
```

This is puzzling because the [Tomcat 7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) lists `relaxedQueryChars` as a valid property of this connector. Is this warning incorrect, or are we doing something the wrong way? (Not surprisingly, this change hasn't been effective; we still get warnings about the curly brackets in the querystring.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273) that this property was only added as of 7.0.87, that is why it does not exist for our version.

It would help if the documentation had "as of" information for newer parameters.